# json.loads() finding my string to be None

Tags: python, json

hi there basically i keep getting

`raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None`
`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

basically i am trying to insert their new score to the list of existing scores for the user who just got a new score (name), i need to get the list from the file and insert the score and then overwrite the old file with the added score

```py
import json
import os

# placeholder values:
t = "A"
fileSuffix = ".txt"
score = 5
name = "john"

fileName = t + fileSuffix
if not os.path.exists(t + fileSuffix):
    open(fileName, "w")
textFile = open(fileName, "r") 
lines = textFile.readlines()
userExists = False
lineToEdit = 0
lineValue = ""

for line in lines:
    if line.find(name) != -1:
        userExists = True
        lineValue = line
        lineToEdit = lines.index(line)

textFile.close()
if userExists:
    lineValue = json.loads(lineValue)
    lineValue.insert(score)
    lines[lineToEdit] = lineValue
    print("user exists, inserted score into list")
else:
    print("user no exist, appending file")
    open(fileName, "a").write("\n" + name + " = ["+ str(score) + "]")
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your txt file ?

Comment: `write("\n" + name + " = ["+ str(score) + "]")` does not create valid json.

Comment: Please simplify this to just set `lineValue` then `json.loads(lineValue)`. Or run it in a debugger to see what's in `lineValue` when it raises the exception. Is that valid JSON?

Comment: "john = [5]" - this is the string that is saved in the file and is the lineValue

Comment: `john = [5]` is not JSON, so it's normal and expected for `json.loads()` to fail with it.

Comment: By contrast, `{"john": [5]}` is something that _would_ be valid JSON.

Comment: how would i convert it from that to a list? 
this is what i'm trying to accomplish

Comment: If you're trying to create key/value pairs, a list is the wrong format to use in the first place; use a dict. `{"user1": [1,2,3], "user2": [4,5,6]}`, etc. `json.dumps()` and similar calls will do the work of dumping that dict back to JSON.

Comment: When you have a list of key/value pairs, you need to do an O(n) search to find the specific key you want; when you have a dict that's efficiently implemented, lookup is O(1). Granted, updating the file in-place is slow, but that's why people who care about doing things efficiently use something like a sqlite database instead of a JSON file. (For a save game format, though, a JSON file that gets rewritten from the beginning over and over may be good enough, as long as you're not saving it too frequently; if you _are_ rewriting it constantly, see again re: sqlite)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy alright thank you just stuck on this one error: 
`TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment` when trying to do  

`dict = json.dumps(textFile.readline())`
`dict[name] = [score]`

to create a new user's list inside the main dictionary

if you have any ideas or if i've done something completely wrong let me know please

Comment: First, don't assign to the name `dict` -- it's the name of a built-in type, and you don't want to overwrite it. Also, the result of a `json.dumps()` operation is a _string_, not a dict; maybe you were thinking about `json.loads()`? And, of course, the line of JSON _needs to actually contain a dict_ (or what JSON calls an "object"), which isn't in evidence as yet.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for your help i've figured it out! wouldn't have been able to without everyone's help; how would i mark it as solved?

Comment: Use the "Add an Answer" button describing how other people with the same problem can solve it. After that answer exists you'll be able to click the checkbox next to it to accept it (there may be a delay before it's clickable), and that will mark the problem solved. Alternately if you don't think the question/answer pair is likely to be helpful to others you can just delete the question (that's frowned on if anyone has added an answer, but it's just comments here so far).

Comment: In the first pass, the code works for me; in the second pass it returns another error. Please show us the full stack trace.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy [What if I answer a question in the comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294791/what-if-i-answer-a-question-in-a-comment)

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine, if I thought anything I'd added in the comments above was an answer to an on-topic question, I would have added it as an answer myself. I'm glad the OP was able to use that guidance to solve their problem, but I don't find this a sufficiently high-quality question to be answerable (within site guidelines asking that folks [answer well-asked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)). The code isn't really a [mre], the problem is barely described via prose, &c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you're trying to create key/value pairs, a list is the wrong format
> to use in the first place; use a dict. {"user1": [1,2,3], "user2":
> [4,5,6]}, etc. json.dumps() and similar calls will do the work of
> dumping that dict back to JSON.

> When you have a list of key/value pairs, you need to do an O(n) search to
> find the specific key you want; when you have a dict that's
> efficiently implemented, lookup is O(1). Granted, updating the file
> in-place is slow, but that's why people who care about doing things
> efficiently use something like a sqlite database instead of a JSON
> file. (For a save game format, though, a JSON file that gets rewritten
> from the beginning over and over may be good enough, as long as you're
> not saving it too frequently; if you are rewriting it constantly, see
> again re: sqlite)

answer from @CharlesDuffy

The issue was I was using an incorrect method to do what I was trying to do; I was using a list where I should have used a dictionary.